# Capitalizing letters read from a file

Tags: c

I'm trying to select certain chars from a file, capitalize them, and display the output. I'm having some trouble selecting the chars:

```
int i;
char c;
char currentChar;
char previousChar = ' ';

inp = fopen("junk.txt", "r");
if(inp == NULL){
    printf("Error opening file, quitting... \n");
    return 1;
}

c = fgetc(inp);
 while(c != EOF){
     if(isalpha(c)){
      putchar(toupper(c));
    c = fgetc(inp);
```

Yes, this is a homework assignment. I'm not looking for the answer, I'm just trying to understand what I'm doing wrong. It doesn't require the use of strings or arrays. The program is supposed to read the contents of a file, capitalize the first letter of each word, and print the results.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What trouble are you having?

Comment: Please provide a little more code. In particular, it's a good idea to show all brackets required to balance what's in your code fragment.

Comment: where is the "Selection of chars" routine?since you want that..here you are not selecting,you are just converting every char to upper case

Comment: You want to capitalize in the display or you want to capitalize in the file ?

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL i guess he wants to display in upper case hence the putchar(). i'm hoping..

Comment: Yes, capitalize in the display.

Comment: You've got the variable `previousChar`, which you need to compare against to see whether this is the first character of a word. But you're never comparing against it or updating it.

Comment: You have to define what a 'word' is.  Short answer; the first alpha char in the file, then, the first alpha character following a space; long answer; there have been books written about this ;)

Comment: `char c;` make that `int c;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [toupper()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/) page of cplusplus.com :

> **int toupper ( int c );**
>
> Convert lowercase letter to uppercase Converts c to its uppercase
>   equivalent if c is a lowercase letter and has an uppercase equivalent.
>   If no such conversion is possible, the value returned is c unchanged.

So no need of the check `if(isalpha(c))` for the char that yoou want to upper case

and your code could look like this

```
char previousChar = ' ';
while((c = fgetc(inp)) != EOF){
   if(!isalpha(previousChar))
       putchar(toupper(c));
   else
       putchar(c);
   previousChar = c;
}
```

According to the alk remark: If your document contains words like `peer2peer` then it will displayed `Peer2Peer` with the previous code. And if you want to displayed `Peer2peer` you have to change your check in this way:

```
char previousChar = ' ';
while((c = fgetc(inp)) != EOF){
   if(previousChar==' ' || previousChar=='\n' || previousChar=='\r' ||
      previousChar=='\t' || previousChar=='\v')
       putchar(toupper(c));
   else
       putchar(c);
   previousChar = c;
}
```

Comment: `The program is supposed to read the contents of a file, capitalize the first letter of each word, and print the results.`

Comment: This would change `peer2peer` to become `Peer2Peer`.

Comment: @alk this is not real word but if his document contains such word, in this case the OP could check for white spaces (`\n`, `\t`, `\v` , `\r`, ` `)  instead

Comment: @alk - That's the point of my comment to the question, the definition of word is quite interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the various possibilities of common word delimiters I'd propose this approach:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
  int result = EXIT_SUCCESS; /* be optimistic! :-) */

  int charCurrent = '\0'
  int charPrevious = ' ';

  while (EOF != (charCurrent = fgetc(stdin)) || (EOF == charPrevious))
  {
    if (isspace(charPrevious))
    {
      charCurrent = toupper(charCurrent);
    }

    charPrevious = fputc(charCurrent, stdout);
  }

  if ((EOF == charCurrent) && !feof(stdin))
  {
    result = EXIT_FAILURE;
    fprintf(stderr, "error getting\n");
  }

  if (EOF == charPrevious)
  {
    result = EXIT_FAILURE;
    fprintf(stderr, "error putting\n");
  }

  return result;
}
```

You then invoke the program:

```
$ ./capitaliser <infile.txt >outfile.txt
```